# Periodically check active clients in Wowza

Tags: wowza

How can I execute something periodically in my Wowza module? I'd like to periodically check the list of active clients to count the minutes they are watching my stream (I want to implement a pay-per-minute counter module). Is it allowed to spawn a thread in my module? Can I register a callback somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know its perfectly ok to spawn threads from your module. The example module sources that you can download from http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?113 has an example which does something similar in `ModuleLogViewerCounts`.

They basically extend `VHostWorkerThread` and set their thread daemon.

There is an article which kind of explains the same here: [Threading in your custom module](https://streamtoolbox.com/simple-threading)